# Powershell remove a column from csv only if a word is present

Tags: powershell

I have a csv with columns A, B, C.  I would like to import that to powershell and only on column C, remove any rows that have the word "Unknown" listed. If Column A or B has "Unknown", they stay, however, if Column C has it, the entire row gets deleted. Per the picture below, Row 4 would be deleted.
Can someone please provide a sample script to do this?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

So, you have 3 problems you need to solve:

1. Import the data from the CSV file
2. Filter it based on the value of column `C`
3. Export the filtered data to a file again

To import, use the aptly named [`Import-Csv` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv):

```
$data = Import-Csv .\path\to\file.csv
```

`Import-Csv` will parse the CSV file and for each row it reads, it will output 1 *object* with properties corresponding to the column names in the header row.

To filter these objects based on the value of their `C` property, use the [`Where-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object):

```
$filteredData = $data |Where-Object C -ne 'Unknown'
```

`Where-Object` will test whether the `C` property on each object does *not* have the value `'Unknown'` (`-ne` = *n*ot *equals*), and discard any object for which that's not the case.

To re-export the filtered data, use the [`Export-Csv` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv):

```
$filteredData |Export-Csv .\path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

---

You can also combine all three statements into a single pipeline expression:

```
Import-Csv .\path\to\file.csv |Where-Object C -ne 'Unknown' |Export-Csv .\path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This "one-liner" approach might be preferable if you're working on large CSV files (> hundreds of thousands of records), as it doesn't require reading the entire CSV file into memory at once.

Comment: @kahoots you're most welcome! If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left. Otherwise, don't forget to accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

$Data = Get-Content "C:\file.csv" | ConvertFrom-Csv
$Data | Where-Object {$_.C-ne 'Unknown'} | Export-Csv "C:\file_New.csv"

Comment: Generally, please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Specifically, I think that Mathias' answer will be more helpful to future readers, and given that your answer provides no additional information, please consider deleting it. As an aside: There's no point in assigning to `$Data`, because `Export-Csv` produces no output.